# Flask & MongoDB - For Loop not working

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo

Having this for Flask:

```
example = mongo.db.example
got_name = example.find({'name':1})
got_lastname = example.find({'lastname':1})

details = {'name' : got_name, 'lastname' : got_lastname}

return render_template('blabla.html', details=details)
```

Then the for loop using Jinja in my HTML (wanting it to be a table):

```
{% for x in details}
<tr>
    <td>{{ x.['name'] }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.['lastname'] }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

But it won't work, it doesn't display anything in my table. I wrote this example above now, but my code is similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use **[`find_one()`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one)** instead of **[`find()`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find)** which returns a cursor to the documents which match the criteria. **[`find_one()`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one)** returns a single document which can then be used in the dictionary, instead of a cursor:

```
example = mongo.db.example
doc = example.find_one()

details = { 'name' : doc['name'], 'lastname' : doc['lastname'] }

return render_template('blabla.html', details=details)
```

Or

```
example = mongo.db.example
details = example.find_one({}, {'name':1, 'lastname':1})

return render_template('blabla.html', details=details)
```

And your template will be

```
<tr>
    <td>{{ details['name'] }}</td>
    <td>{{ details['lastname'] }}</td>
</tr>
```

---

If you want to iterate the whole collection and return a list if documents with just the `name` and `lastname` fields, then you should use the **[`find()`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find)** method. 
If you have a relatively small dataset, the following code will convert the entire result set (Cursor) into a list (everything is pulled into memory):

```
example = mongo.db.example
details = list(example.find({}, {'name': 1, 'lastname': 1}))

return render_template('blabla.html', details=details)
```

Then iterate the list in your template

```
{% for doc in details}
<tr>
    <td>{{ doc['name'] }}</td>
    <td>{{ doc['lastname'] }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Everything works fine, but then I tried to iterate using your method. I've `details = list(bans.find({}, {'Nume codat' : 1, 'SteamID' : 1, 'Motiv' : 1}))`, then `<td>{{ x.['Nume codat'] }}</td>` but I get „TemplateSyntaxError: expected name or number” @ `<td>{{ x.['Nume codat'] }}</td>`. Thanks for the reply, though!

Comment: Weird, works if I delete the dot, ex. `{{ x.['bla'] }}` was wrong, but `{{ x['blabla'] }}` works. Should it work or was something done wrong by your side?

Comment: My bad, that was a typo on your part I failed to correct in giving my answer. I have updated the answer to reflect the correct approach.

Comment: One more question: how do I make it so the first display is actually the last data that was inserted into the database? Cause if I insert some data now, it'll actually display at the bottom, after the other data. I want it to be inversed, hope you catch my drift.

Comment: You can try sort on the _id key (if your documents' `_id` key is an `ObjectId`) as `details = list(example.find({}, {'name': 1, 'lastname': 1}).sort('_id', -1))`

Answer (score 0):

Your template would actually have to be more like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>{{ details['name'] }}</td>
    <td>{{ details['lastname'] }}</td>
</tr>
```

No loops.

If you had an array of dictionaries, then you could use your initial template.