# dict returning as string through flask url

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo

Using Flask pymongo for a school project, a site on sharing recipes.
I want to return the dict i use on my home page so that the site knows what recipe it should be showing when clicked.However, in the terminal it seems to return (the way i want) as a dict but when its actually returning a string  of the dict so i cant use it.

From App.py:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    if request.method == 'GET' or request.form.get('search') == '':
        recipes = mongo.db.recipe.find()
        return render_template('home.html', recipes=recipes)
```

From home page: loops through the recipes in mongodb so i can take values like recipe.recipe_name etc.

```
{% for recipe in recipes %}
<a href="{{url_for('view_recipe', recipe=recipe)}}"
```

Am i returning the variable back wrong? is there another way to do this?
All help very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

When getting the request to backend, you have to do `json.loads(your_json)` which can be used in backend. It converts the string of dict you mentioned to valid json.

Comment: It came back with this: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

Comment: When you print `recipes` from  `recipes = mongo.db.recipe.find()`, what does it show?

Comment: <pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x041817F0>

Comment: You are sending a pymongo cursor which actually points to that data in mongo. It is not a valid json.
You have to iterate through cursor to get the value you want.

Comment: can you share what is in your recipe database?

Comment: I loop through in my second code block i posted. for recipe in recipes and then i try and return recipe.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213267/discussion-between-overflow95-and-matthew-casey).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41739179/flask-mongodb-for-loop-not-working

Check this answer.